# AWS DynamoDB iOS Query

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I followed the tutorial from the official AWS guide, but what is not explained is how to query for secondary indexes, ones I created myself. So what method would I call on queryExpression and how would I use the method (what would I do exactly if I have say three secondary indexes and they each should have a given value for the query)?

Comment: You should post your table schema, the definition of global/local secondary index, and code snippets you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

From the AWS DynamoDB IOS developers Guide:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/dynamodb_om.html

> The Query API enables you to query a table or a secondary index. You
>   must provide a hash key value in AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression. To query
>   an index, you must also specify the indexName. You must specify the
>   hashKeyAttribute if you query a global secondary with a different
>   hashKey. If the table or index has a range key, you can optionally
>   refine the results by providing a range key value and a condition. The
>   query:expression: method takes two parameters—the class of the
>   resulting object and an instance of AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression. In the
>   following example, we query the Books index table to find all books
>   with author of “John Smith” and price less than 50:

And it  would be something like this:

```
AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression *queryExpression = [AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression new];

queryExpression.indexName = @"Author-Price-index";

queryExpression.hashKeyAttribute = @"Author";
queryExpression.hashKeyValues = @"John Smith";

queryExpression.rangeKeyConditionExpression = @"Price < :val";
queryExpression.expressionAttributeValues = @{@":val":@50};

[[dynamoDBObjectMapper query:[Book class]
          expression:queryExpression]
continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
     if (task.error) {
         NSLog(@"The request failed. Error: [%@]", task.error);
     }
     if (task.exception) {
         NSLog(@"The request failed. Exception: [%@]", task.exception);
     }
     if (task.result) {
         AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput *paginatedOutput = task.result;
         for (Book *book in paginatedOutput.items) {
             //Do something with book.
         }
     }
     return nil;
 }];
```